# Recurring payments URL for Vanco payment processor

Tags: payment-processor, recurring-contributions, vanco

Could someone provide an explanation (with an example) for the recurring payments URL field found on the Add Payment Processor form when using Vanco Payment Processor? It is my understanding it is used for processing the Instant Payment Notification (IPN), a message service that notifies you of events related to your payment transactions.

Comment: The [Github repo](https://github.com/backoffice/Vanco-processor/tree/master/vanco.directpayment.processor) includes an "Installation instructions.doc" - does that help at all? You might be able to ask via the issue queue there also, if the docs don't already make it clear.

Comment: The instructions only state "fill in your test and/or live account settings",  I will send another request to Back Office Thinking, the developers of the module for Vanco Payment Processing.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Mike,  that URL is not needed. Just complete the top 4 lines (userID, password, site URL, API URL)

You do need to send Vanco the URL of the VancoHistory.php file so that they can send recurring notifications on that URL.

Hope this helps

Comment: The only thing I can find is:

recur_history.xml
history.xml

Comment: Is it possible the file is called Utils.php

Answer (score 0):

Mike, as pkeogan stated, the field does not need to be populated for Vanco.

I believe that some payment processors have different URL's to submit recurring payments to, thus the need for this field.  In Vanco's case, all transactions should be submitted to the one, single URL.

If the Recurring URL is not specified, CiviCRM defaults to the API url.